# Custom Game Engine Rendering Blurry Images After Movement

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, rendering, game-engine

I' m trying to create my own game engine. So far, I can render a background (map) and draw the player.

[image]

Also, I created a control system for the player, which is working correctly.
But when I move the player the image becomes blurry.

[image]

Below, I will provide all the code I think might causes this rendering problem.
First of all the HTML and the CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/global.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <script src="utils.js"></script>
    <script src="KeyboardController.js"></script>
    <script src="Canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="Spritesheet.js"></script>
    <script src="Sprite.js"></script>
    <script src="World.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Now, the js which starts the engine:

```
const BLOCK_W = 16
const BLOCK_H = 16

const canvas = new Canvas({
  title: "Engine",
  width: 240,
  height: 160
})

const keys = new KeyboardController()
initKeyboard()


const dirt = new Sprite({ filename: "./img/dirt.png" })
const grass = new Sprite({ filename: "./img/grass.png" })
const brickWall = new Sprite({ filename: "./img/brick-wall.png" })
const sky = new Sprite({ filename: "./img/sky.png" })
const mario = new Sprite({ filename: "./img/mario.png" })

const MARIO_SPEED = 0.2
let MARIO_X = 1 * 16
let MARIO_Y = 7 * 16

const world = new World({ mapWidth: 15 })
world.createMap(
  "Super Mario Map",
  [
    [sky, { start: 0, end: 119 }],
    [grass, { start: 120, end: 134 }],
    [dirt, { start: 135, end: 149 }],
  ]
)


function loop() {
  
  world.drawMap("Super Mario Map")
  
  if (keys.w) { MARIO_Y -= MARIO_SPEED }
  if (keys.a) { MARIO_X -= MARIO_SPEED }
  if (keys.d) { MARIO_X += MARIO_SPEED }
  
  mario.draw(MARIO_X, MARIO_Y)


  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: 0;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.Game-Container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #121212;
}

.Canvas {
  /* outline: 1px solid #000; */
  background: #bebebe;
}
```

And the Sprite class, which draws/renders the player

```
class Sprite {
  constructor({ filename }) {

    this.TO_RADIANS = Math.PI / 180
    this.filename = filename
    this.image = null
    this.spritesheet = null
    this.isPattern = false
    this.pattern = null
    this.patternXTimes = 0

    if (this.filename instanceof Spritesheet) {
      this.spritesheet = filename
      this.image = this.spritesheet.image
      console.log(`Loaded spritesheet ${this.filename}`)
    } else if (filename != undefined && filename !== "" && filename !== null) {
      this.load(this.filename)
      console.log(`Loaded sprite ${this.filename}`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Unable to load spritesheet/sprite ${this.filename}`)
    }

  }

  load(filename) {
    this.image = new Image()
    this.image.src = filename
  }

  toPattern(xTimes) {
    this.patternXTimes = xTimes
    this.pattern = Context.context.createPattern(this.image, "repeat")
  }

  draw(x, y, config) {

    if (config === undefined) { canvas.context.drawImage(this.image, x, y) }
    else if (utils.isNumeric(config) && config >= 0) {

      let res = utils.i2xy(config, 15)
      canvas.context.drawImage(this.image,
        res.x * 16, res.y * 16, 16, 16,
        x, y, 16, 16
      )

    }
    
  }
}
```

Anything else you think might be relatable to this, I will provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the MARIO_SPEED is the solution